# Recommended way to set AWS credentials in code

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm searching for best way(if exists) to set up aws credentials in my application, that runs on non-EC2 instance. As of now code works well with profiles and\or environment variables but im wondering if there is a way to set aws credentials from code. i.e how i can make sure my code picks up aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key values i get from another internal service during runtime?

The service which gives me credentials is a trusted internal service(not exposed to outside our network) and give lot of flexibility w.r.t. changing creds runtime, without new deployment or without touching prod box.

Comment: They can be stored in App.Config, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: yeah, no storing on the machine, that is what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, i.e you are outside of using Ec2 Roles on machines,  the recommend way is in app.config so you can flexibly change them if you need to imho. But with a couple of things added.

**Encrypt your app.config**

You can I believe use encryption of your App.config settings also to make this more secure.

This guide my help you. https://magenic.com/thinking/encrypting-configuration-sections-in-net

**Limit your Api Access Key to only what you need.**

You should make sure you set a specific user with specific permissions to the resource it needs and nothing else. I.e Don't user your programmatic access for your app.config. Set a new one up.

**Rotate that Programmatic key every 3 months or sooner**

Make sure you rotate your keys and review the access level.